# div disappearing while changing the height of Safari and Chrome browsers

Tags: safari, html-rendering

Visit this URL using Safari or Chrome browser:
http://aspspider.net/sunlight1000/two_col_div_layout_w3valid.htm
Set the width of the browser’s window to make sure the height of the Green box is greater than the height of the Red box. Then grab the lower edge of the browser’s window and drag it to the lower edge of the Green box and play around it. You will notice the Red box disappears when the lower edge of the browser’s window goes higher than the lower edge of the Green box. Then continue to shrink up the height of the browser’s window and the Red box will appear again. You will notice the Red box appears again exactly at the moment the lower edge of the browser’s window reaches the low edge of Red box. The Red box never disappears in other browsers (IE, FF and Opera). Is this a bug in Safari or some kind of “feature”? In any case I will be highly appreciated if someone suggests me a workaround to avoid disappearing of the Red box in Safari.
Here is the code of above mentioned page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>2 Column Fixed Liquid CSS Layout</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .wrapper
    {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
    .wrapright
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: Blue;
    }
    .right
    {
        margin-left: 160px;
        background-color: Lime;
    }
    .left
    {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: -100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapright">
        <div class="right">
            LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUER ADIPISCING ELIT, SED DIAM NONUMMY NIBH
            EUISMOD TINCIDUNT UT LAOREET DOLORE MAGNA ALIQUAM ERAT VOLUTPAT.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div style="background-color: red;">
            LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUER ADIPISCING ELIT, ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for your final layout, but based on the demo layout: seems like the negative 100% margin could be causing the issue. The behavior appears to be the same if you take away the float and margin declarations and do a position: absolute on the .left div. As long as the container is relatively positioned, I think you'll get the same end result.

Comment: I have found the solution. Just added float: left; line to the .wrapper class. See example on http://aspspider.net/sunlight1000/two_col_div_layout_w3valid_0.htm